# Como desinstalar o Cordova e Ionic completamente do windows

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova, windows

Preciso desinstalar o Cordova e o Ionic da minha máquina completamente sem deixar nenhuma referência ou cache para que ao reinstalar eu garanta que todas as instâncias são absolutamente novas.

Gostaria de saber qual o comando npm para isso?

Comment: Baixa o IObit Uninstaller, e desinstala por completo com ele...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rode:

```
npm uninstall cordova ionic
```

Se você pretende reinstalar posteriormente, precisa limpar o cache:

```
npm cache clean -f
npm install npm -g
```

Se o problema persistir, é recomendado que você desinstale e instale o node:

```
npm uninstall node
apt-get purge npm
apt-get install npm
npm install node -g
```

Answer (score 1):

forma que funciono pra mim:

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm uninstall -g ionic
```